# install bluetooth drivers on dell xps 9550

Tags: bluetooth

Usually bluetooth works ok.
Got jaybird x3 headphones that don't connect.
Vendor suggested I'd install Bluetooth drivers.

How to do that for Ubuntu?

Comment: Can you confirm if the headphones connect to your other devices such as your phone?

Comment: Yes they connect to my phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use blueman driver:

```
sudo apt install blueman
```

To put the jaybird into proper pairing mode, you have to have them off, then hold the power button until it turns on, AND starts pairing.